# Hiding Upload button of kendo upload

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I want to hide the 'Upload file' button of kendo upload since I am using my custom button for uploading file.

I have written the code on select file of kendo upload as,

```
function onSelect() {
    $('.k-upload-selected').css("display", "none");
}
```

I have tried with the following css also,

```
.k-upload-selected{
    display: none;
}
```

But the upload button is still there...

Please help me..[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

`$(".k-button.k-upload-button").css("visibility", "hidden");`

after initializing the widget. [Example Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OLUXI)

Answer (score 1):

for hide:

```
$('.k-upload-selected').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

for completely removing

```
$('.k-upload-selected').remove();
```

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ILok/63)

Answer (score 1):

You simply use

```
<style>
  .k-clear-selected, .k-upload-selected{
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>
```

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/@vanquan223/uRAMozoF/3)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kendo for Angular you need to set **encapsulation** in the component to **ViewEncapsulation.None**.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'upload-selector',
    templateUrl: 'upload.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['upload.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Angular, [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/knowledge-base/external-btn-uploading/) is Kendo's official example for it.

---

Note: you may need to apply `::ng-deep` (missing in the example) on the CSS class to make it work:

```css
::ng-deep .k-actions {
  display: none;
}
```